# python - plotting N by 1 number of plots when N is unknown

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot

I currently am plotting multiple plots across 4 axis using seaborn. In order to do this, I manually select nrows=4 and then run 4 boxplots at once.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

data=np.random.randn(1000)
label = ['A','B','C','D'] * 250

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'label': prod1,
 'data': data
})

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(12, 16)

sns.boxplot(data=df[df['label']=='A'], y='data', ax=ax1)
sns.boxplot(data=df[df['label']=='B'], y='data', ax=ax2)
sns.boxplot(data=df[df['label']=='C'], y='data', ax=ax3)
sns.boxplot(data=df[df['label']=='D'], y='data', ax=ax4)
```

I would like to rewrite this function so that it automatically recognizes the unique number of labels, creates the number of axes automatically, then plots.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharey=True)
```

[makes `ax` a NumPy array of axes](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). This array can be one- or two-dimensional (depending on the value of the `nrows` and `ncols` parameters),
so calling `ax.ravel()` is used to ensure it is one-dimensional. 
Now you can loop over [`zip(label, ax.ravel())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to call `sns.boxplot` once for each label and axes.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(12, 16)
for labeli, axi in zip(label, ax.ravel()):
    sns.boxplot(data=df[df['label']==labeli], y='data', ax=axi)
```

Note that `zip` ends when the shortest of the iterators end. So even though
`label` has length 1000, only the first 4 items are used in the loop since there
are only 4 axes.

Alternatively, just assign `label = ['A','B','C','D']` since that variable is not used anywhere else (at least, not in the posted code).

Comment: Thank you! Works great!  You mention ax.ravel ensures that it's 1 dimensional. Does that mean this would need to be different if it was, say, a 2x2 plot?

Comment: By using `ax.ravel()` the code will not have to change 
if you use `plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharey=True)`. That's the reason for using `ax.ravel()` even though it is not necessary with just `nrows=4`.